# Flight delay Info

Tags: air-travel

Flight LS765, 21/02/2022.
Manchester to Malta
This flight was originally delayed due to weather in Malta but then the new flight time was delayed due to a problem with the plane, we changed planes and then waited for bags and food/drinks etc to arrive. How can I find details of timings - Jet2 say it was weather so no compensation but only first part was weather. Is there anyway I can find details?